# Iphone 4s upgrade to iOS7 - Calendar appointments are gone

Tags: iphone, calendar, ipad, ios

Upgraded my iPhone 4s to iOS 7; now my calendar appointments are completely missing from the phone. And it will not add a new appointment - I enter the data and hit "Done" but when I go to view, it's not there.

To clarify, I use a Google calendar on Outlook on my PC and sync THAT calendar to the iPhone and iPad calendars.  However, the PC Outlook calendar wasn't syncing (I didn't realize that until too late).  I used the iPhone and the Ipad for most calendar data entries.

When I checked iCloud, it showed only the partial calendar on the PC (Outlook).

The good news is that the calendar on my iPad is up-to-date - BUT I'm reluctant to manually sync it to anything in case I lose it.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your Google calendar to your iPhone 4s directly: Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Google > Sign in and select to sync the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1. Go to Settings -> Mail -> Default Calendar
2. Make sure "HOME" calendar is checked.

All my appointments reappeared and I am now able to add appointments. Hope it works for all of you.